# Jooq no entities found

Tags: jooq, jooq-codegen

https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-jpa/

I want to generate from JPA Entites

but I saw something like this

This can have several reasons, including:

- The packages you've listed do not exist (com.example.member.member)
- The entities in the listed packages are not on the JPADatabase classpath (you must compile them before running jOOQ's codegen, see "how to organise your dependencies" in the manual: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-jpa/!)

this is my gradle.build

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        /* See above for the correct groupId */
        classpath 'org.jooq:jooq-codegen:3.18.5'
        classpath 'com.h2database:h2:2.1.214'
        classpath 'org.jooq:jooq-meta-extensions-hibernate:3.18.5'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.6'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

import org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool
import org.jooq.meta.jaxb.*

task generateCode() {
    GenerationTool.generate(new org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Configuration()
            .withGenerator(new Generator()
                    .withDatabase(new Database()
                            .withName("org.jooq.meta.extensions.jpa.JPADatabase")
//                            .withIncludes(".*")
                            .withProperties(

                                    // A comma separated list of Java packages, that contain your entities
                                    new Property()
                                            .withKey("packages")
                                            .withValue("com.example.member.member"),

                                    // Whether JPA 2.1 AttributeConverters should be auto-mapped to jOOQ Converters.
                                    // Custom <forcedType/> configurations will have a higher priority than these auto-mapped converters.
                                    // This defaults to true.
                                    new Property()
                                            .withKey("useAttributeConverters")
                                            .withValue("true"),

                                    // The default schema for unqualified objects:
                                    //
                                    // - public: all unqualified objects are located in the PUBLIC (upper case) schema
                                    // - none: all unqualified objects are located in the default schema (default)
                                    //
                                    // This configuration can be overridden with the schema mapping feature
                                    new Property()
                                            .withKey("unqualifiedSchema")
                                            .withValue("none")
                            )
                    )
                    .withTarget(new Target()
                            .withPackageName(projectDir.toString() + "jooq.generated.example")
                            .withDirectory("src/main/java")
                    )))
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server'
    implementation group: 'org.jooq', name: 'jooq', version: '3.18.5'
//    implementation group: 'org.jooq', name: 'jooq-meta-extensions-hibernate', version: '3.18.5'
    runtimeOnly "io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-native-macos:4.1.76.Final:osx-aarch_64"
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    runtimeOnly 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I don't know what to do

Comment: Well, did you add the entities as a dependency to your code generation run, as suggested by the quoted error message? Where are they in your project setup?